# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, assemblybinding

I am getting this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have this version in my bin folder

[image]

here is my binding information

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

what is missing?

Comment: Looks like one (_or more_) of your projects has reference to v3.5.0.0, why you didn't update that project(s)?

Comment: I wanted to post on twitter using Twitterizer2 dll and getting error, I think Twitterizer2 is internally using old version of json.net and to fix that I have added a mapping but getting error.

Comment: Changing `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />` to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />` doesn't help?